# Equation of a hyperbolic slot

Tags: linear-algebra

I am here because I need help on a subject that I wanted to solve on my own. Here it is :

The purpose is to find the function $y=f(x)$ of the hyperbolic slot that we can see in orange on the following picture. The system consist of an inclined rod fixed to a disk, which turn around the $y$ axis without touching the $X$ shaped arch.

[The hyperbolic slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UoIQ.png)

I represented the rod as a vector in $3D$ space with those $3$ systems :

[Initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCNFJ.png)

So the rod can be expressed in the coordinate system R1 that we can see on the picture, as :

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
-Lcos(\beta)cos(\theta)+e\\
Lcos(\beta)sin(\theta)\\
-Lcos(\beta)
\end{array}
\right] $$

If I multiply that vector by the rotational matrix around the $y$ axis :

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
cos(\alpha)&0&-sin(\alpha)\\
0&1&0\\
sin(\alpha)&0&cos(\alpha)
\end{array}
\right] $$

We obtain :

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
cos⁡(\alpha)[-Lcos⁡(\beta)cos⁡(\theta)+e]+Lsin(\alpha)sin⁡(\beta)\\
Lcos⁡(\beta)sin(\theta)\\
sin⁡(\alpha)[-L.cos⁡(\beta)cos⁡(\theta)+e]-Lcos(\alpha)sin⁡(\beta)
\end{array}
\right] $$

If I call the $3$ components of that vector $x,y$ and $z$, the purpose is to express $x$ and $y$ when $z=0$ because if $z=0$, that means the rod is crossing the $(x,y)$ plane. I came up with these $2$ expressions for $x$ and $y$ :

$$ x(\alpha) = \frac{e*sin(\beta)}{sin⁡(\alpha)cos⁡(\beta)cos⁡(\theta)+cos(\alpha)sin⁡(\beta)}   $$
$$ y(\alpha) = \frac{e*sin⁡(\alpha)cos(\beta)sin(\theta)}{sin⁡(\alpha)cos⁡(\beta)cos⁡(\theta)+cos(\alpha)sin⁡(\beta)}   $$

They correctly represent the slot as we can see on the following picture :

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcAsh.png)

(I took $L=130$mm, $e=40$mm, $beta = 20°$, $theta = 50°$ and alpha between $0$ and $150°$)

But now I want to have juste one equation y=f(x), but I don't find how to eliminate the alpha. Can someone help me please ?

Thank you and have a good day

Comment: But it's plain from the graph that $y$ is not a function of $x$.  It most cases, there are two values of $y$ corresponding to a single value of $x$.